# Testing D programmes on FreeBSD to Compile on OSX

Tags: linux, macos, freebsd, d

I have never had Apple computer. For a while, I am running Ubuntu on my laptop, and written many programme codes in D2. All of them are terminal applications, there is no GUI.

Now I am planning to buy a Macbook, but I am not sure if my programmes will be running as expected on OSX. I am not able to test it, but I thought if I install FreeBSD and compile my codes on it, maybe it will be compiled on OSX as well. Does anyone have experience or knowledge about this? Because I am mainly writing programmes for Linux servers, and if OSX will put me into hard situation, I may start considering a normal laptop.

P.S. In case anyone asks, I hate graphic applications on Linux, I want OSX, so I can both run Photoshop etc, and also natively run and compile my programmes as well.

---

P.S. In many cases, either Phobos libraries or POSIX codes are used. But there is access to /etc, /var folders for file access. Shared Memory and Unix Sockets are used as well.

Comment: Unfortunately we have no idea how portable your code is, since all we know is that it runs in the terminal.  It will "probably" be fine.

Comment: Get together with a friend who has an Apple laptop and test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are indeed good that if your software compiles on two different UNIX platform, it will also compile on a third. But you can't expect without testing on Mac OS X you won't have specific issues.

**Directories**

To make your application more portable, you indeed should take in consideration each OS stores elsewhere configuration file. For example, Ubuntu uses /etc, FreeBSD uses /usr/local/etc and Mac OS X uses /private/etc (but provides a symbolic link to /etc).

The use of /var is more universal.

**Network**

For UNIX sockets, code is similar. If you've TCP stuff, there are some minor subtle differences between Linux on one side, and FreeBSD and Mac OS X on other sides, like the fact an tcp6 connection will listen only on ipv6 or both on ipv4 and ipv6. But generally, all is fine and compatible on this side.

**Shared memory**

Shared memory generally depends of external libraries. Indeed, this is a really OS dependent area. But as far as I can tell from http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node27.html, this is handled by D, so you shouldn't be troubled.

**Another strategy**

A good strategy could be to create a virtual machine to test if your code compiles on Mac OS X directly.

http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox gives a solution, and https://askubuntu.com/questions/303725/virtualbox-how-to-install-os-x-guest-under-ubuntu-host seems to support the idea that should work on Ubuntu too.

There is a legal issue involved, as Apple EULA restricts the installation of Mac OS X on computers built by Apple. As a contract can't violate the local laws, the question of the enforceability of this clause in various jurisdictions is open.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I am planning to buy a Macbook, but I am not sure if my programmes will be running as expected on OSX.

Unless your programs use OS-specific functions (e.g. they import `core.sys.freebsd.*` or `core.sys.linux.*`), D programs should run just fine on any platform. (No guarantee, but it's rather likely.) In your case, it's even more likely, as Linux, FreeBSD and OS X are all POSIX-compatible.

Comment: I better check that `core.sys.linux`. Because I used `core.sys.*` in many places.

Comment: You could always use version (OS_HERE) { // do things } to make it compatible with as many platforms possible.